# Xamarin.iOS app crash after splash screen - condition 'oti' not met

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm running into an issue with one of my apps. It's installing and launching fine (installing from TestFlight) but then almost immediately after showing the splash screen it crashes. The device logs are not telling me much and I thought maybe some of you might have ran into this before and hopefully have a solution. Part of the device logs that I think is the reason for the crash (let me know if you need more):

`error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/mini-generic-sharing.c:906, condition 'oti' not met`

I found this [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#assertion-at-monometadatageneric-sharingc704-condition-oti-not-met), that describes similar issue but I'm not sure what a non-Thumb/Thumb linking is and how and what I should change to fix it.

The intriguing part about this problem is that the app **works perfectly fine on the iPhone 6s Plus with iOS version 12.3.1** but it **crashes after splash screen on the iPhone 5c with iOS version 10.3.3**.

NOTE: I'm building the ipa package using DevOps with xamarin SDK 5.18.1 and xcode version 10.3

EDIT: Full logs

```
80  apsd(PersistentConnection)  2019-09-12 21:32:53 +1000 apsd[80]: <PCDispatchTimer: 0x1667c440> performing call back
80  apsd(PersistentConnection)  2019-09-12 21:32:53 +1000 apsd[80]: <PCDispatchTimer: 0x1667c440> is invalidated 
23  CommCenter  #I SIM has not requested to be notified on entering idle screen, not processing
80  apsd(PersistentConnection)  2019-09-12 21:32:53 +1000 apsd[80]: <PCDispatchTimer: 0x1667c440> in call back event handler
64  assertiond  Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.progrunning.visualstimulation[0x7b5][64]
49  SpringBoard Running <SBAppExitedWorkspaceTransaction: 0x8799840> for transition request:
49  SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x17db6930; VisualStimulati; pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x8717c50; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)>
49  SpringBoard(FrontBoard) <FBApplicationProcess: 0x17db6930; VisualStimulati; pid: 229> exited.
230 OTACrashCopier  Starting OTACrashCopier
228 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)   Saved type '109(<private>)' report (2 of max 25) at <private>
228 ReportCrash Formulating report for corpse[229] <private>
228 ReportCrash __crash_info: [<private>] '<private>'
63  backboardd  Effective device orientation changed to: unknown
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Stopping orientation detection.
228 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)   cr_update: <private>
228 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)   cr_update: <private>
63  backboardd  Turning off orientation events.
49  SpringBoard(KeyboardArbiter)    HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/mini-generic-sharing.c:906, condition `oti' not met
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:52 [TRACE] (MvxForms) Showing of native host View in Forms is not supported.
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:52 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) iOSNavigation
67  locationd   Client com.apple.springboard disconnected
67  locationd   message 'kCLConnectionMessageWatchdog' received from client 'com.apple.springboard'
67  locationd   Client com.apple.springboard (0x159ec400) is subscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageGyroBiasEstimation
67  locationd   message 'kCLConnectionMessageGyroBiasEstimation' received from client 'com.apple.springboard'
67  locationd   location disabled system-wide, denying executable com.apple.springboard
67  locationd   getClientEffectiveRegistrationResult, /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard, com.apple.springboard, , CLClientRegistrationResult, kCLClientRegistrationResultFailedUnavailable, CLCommonLocationServicesEnabled, 0
67  locationd   location disabled system-wide, denying executable com.apple.springboard
67  locationd   getClientEffectiveRegistrationResult, /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard, com.apple.springboard, , CLClientRegistrationResult, kCLClientRegistrationResultFailedUnavailable, CLCommonLocationServicesEnabled, 0
67  locationd   Client com.apple.springboard connected
49  SpringBoard(CoreMotion) Stopping device motion, mode=0x<private>
49  SpringBoard Root transaction complete: <SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction: 0xc165480>
49  SpringBoard Enabling home screen icon rotation for reason: SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction
49  SpringBoard(CoreMotion) Starting device motion, mode=0x22,useAccelerometer=0,useGyro=1,useCompass=0,fUseNorthRef=0,buildingGYTT=0
49  SpringBoard Enabling home screen icon rotation for reason: <SBCrossfadeIconZoomAnimator:0xc1690e0>
49  SpringBoard Setting _lastBKUserEventTimerMode=0 with duration=-1.000000
49  SpringBoard Disabling idle timer because the next idle duration < 0.
49  SpringBoard returning -1 from _nextIdleTimeDuration because SBAutoDimTime is less than 0
49  SpringBoard returning -1 from _nextLockTimeDuration because SBAutoLockTime is less than 0
49  SpringBoard Undimming for source: programmatic
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:52 [TRACE] (MvxForms) Showing of native host View in Forms is not supported.
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:52 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) iOSNavigation
23  CommCenter  #I CTServerConnection from pid 229 has closed (conn=0x146b3610)
23  CommCenter  #E Client 229 (<private>) not permitted to register for event kCTEventIndicatorSignalStrength(16); ignored registration
23  CommCenter  #I   ==== client 229 (<private>) registered for event kCTEventRegistrationDataStatus(55) (now total 2)
23  CommCenter  #I   ==== client 229 (<private>) registered for event kCTEventWirelessTechnologyChange(139) (now total 1)
23  CommCenter  #I CTServerConnection from pid 229[<private>] is named '<private>'.
23  CommCenter  #I  -- connection has entitlements: <private>
23  CommCenter  #I New CTServerConnection from pid 229 (conn=0x146b3610)
229 VisualStimulation.iOS(Foundation)   *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
229 VisualStimulation.iOS(Foundation)   *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
63  backboardd  Effective device orientation changed to: faceUp
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Got latest sample: 5 @ 5268.808328
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Updating client handler: Orientation FaceUp, Callback mode: -1
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Received orientation. (Ambiguous to FaceUp) Timestamp 5268.808328
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Notify from, Unexpected -> FaceUp
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Waiting for the first orientation to come in
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  Starting orientation detection with accelFrequency 10.000000, isIpad, 0, decimationRate, 1
63  backboardd(CoreMotion)  fHasSeenACaseLatchCoverOnce, 0
63  backboardd  Turning on orientation events.
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvxForms) Showing of native host View in Forms is not supported.
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) iOSNavigation
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) AppStart: Application Startup - On UI thread
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Secondary end
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: LastChance start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: InpcInterception start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: InpcInterception start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: NavigationSerializer start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
49  SpringBoard Destination SBNotificationBannerDestination is now ready to receive notifications
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view BaseContentPage
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Views start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewsContainer start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Application Initialize - On background thread
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: App start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Load navigation routes
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: NavigationService
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Create App
23  CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib) QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x0051 Bin=['01 15 00 80 03 03 04 00 00 51 00 09 00 14 06 00 AB F5 8C FF 10 00']
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: CommandHelper start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: StringToTypeParser start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Bootstrap actions
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: ViewDispatcher start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Singleton Cache start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: MvvmCross settings start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: PlatformServices start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: FirstChance start
229 VisualStimulation.iOS   2019-09-12 21:32:51 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup) Setup: Primary start
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) CFSM2 foreground (current/state) out = (1/1)
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) CFSM2 foreground (current/proposed/state) in = (1/1/3)
23  CommCenter  #I BundleID: <private> is a foreground app
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Set appCompactState object 14880 for key com.progrunning.visualstimulation
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) com.progrunning.visualstimulation: Foreground: true
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Continue with bundle name com.progrunning.visualstimulation, is front 1
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Going to Foreground, new flags 0x0, initial value 0x0, enabled 0
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) app name com.progrunning.visualstimulation isForeground 1  hasForegroundApps 1, current idea of foreground 0 disp (null)
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Check for bundle name com.progrunning.visualstimulation returns 0
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) Entry, display name com.progrunning.visualstimulation uuid 252190E5-6FB0-3CB3-869B-E4F749AD141D pid 229 isFront 1
111 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator) 229 com.progrunning.visualstimulation: ForegroundRunning (most elevated: ForegroundRunning)
23  CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.AppObserver: observe_block_invoke: 5. app got notification state: new counter=6
23  CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.AppObserver: notifyAboutFrontAppChange: notifyAboutFrontAppChange : app: <private>; pid: 229; net: 0
23  CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.AppObserver: observe_block_invoke: 4. app got notification state: pid=229 for <private>
23  CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.AppObserver: observe_block_invoke: FBSDisplayLayoutUpdateHandler: app <private> (UIApplicationElement 1 hasKeyboardFocus 0)
32  sharingd    SystemUI changed: 0x10 -> 0x0
32  sharingd    SystemUI unknown identifier: 'com.progrunning.visualstimulation'
23  CommCenter  #I CSIAppInfo.AppObserver: observe_block_invoke: FBSDisplayLayoutUpdateHandler: update start
49  SpringBoard(CoreMotion) Stopping device motion, mode=0x<private>
42  mediaserverd(CoreMedia) -CMSessionMgr- cmsmHandleApplicationStateChange: CMSession: Client com.progrunning.visualstimulation with pid '229' is now Foreground Running. Background entitlement: NO
49  SpringBoard Dismissing banner for notification (null)
49  SpringBoard(MobileCoreServices) Looking up unclipped icon for app <private>
49  SpringBoard Disabling home screen icon rotation for reason: <SBCrossfadeIconZoomAnimator:0xc1690e0>
49  SpringBoard Disabling home screen icon rotation for reason: SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction
49  SpringBoard(AssertionServices)  [com.progrunning.visualstimulation] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.progrunning.visualstimulation[0x7b5][64]
64  assertiond  Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.progrunning.visualstimulation[0x7b5][64]
49  SpringBoard Running <SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction: 0xc165480> for transition request:
49  SpringBoard(Security)   [leaf CheckLeafMarkerOid IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
93  securityd   cert[0]: IssuerCommonName =(path)[]> 0
93  securityd   cert[0]: CheckLeafMarkerOid =(leaf)[]> 0
93  securityd   cert[0]: SubjectCommonName =(leaf)[]> 0
49  SpringBoard(Security)   could not enable test hierarchy: ApplePinningAllowTestCertsiPhoneApplicationSigning not true
49  SpringBoard(Security)   [leaf CheckLeafMarkerOid IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
93  securityd   cert[0]: IssuerCommonName =(path)[]> 0
93  securityd   cert[0]: CheckLeafMarkerOid =(leaf)[]> 0
93  securityd   cert[0]: SubjectCommonName =(leaf)[]> 0
49  SpringBoard(Security)   could not enable test hierarchy: ApplePinningAllowTestCertsiPhoneApplicationSigning not true
```

EDIT: After updates to Xamarin.Forms and other 3rd part libraries the issue went away. I'm not exactly sure what was the casue of it in the first place though.

Comment: Hi ,you can show the full error log .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've edited my question with full log from the device

Comment: Thanks for updating , do you use `MvvmCross` in project ?You can update VS and Xcode to the latest version to have a try.

Comment: Yes, I do use MvvmCross. I'm using latest version of VS and xcode

Comment: No, the latest version of xcode is 11.And the VS in Windows is 16.3.1 .

Comment: Oh, true. I was thinking of my local env. You're right, I will try using more recent version in DevOps (I'll check what's available) and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah , if error disappears or other problems after updaing let me know *.^

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I tried updating the pipeline to latest Mono SDK and Xcode but the build was failing. I then tried running the app on a device from VS and I ran into another wall, related to ?bindings? https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7083. I will try again after installing the latest VS update and see if my issue can be repro-ed locally first